# How to fix 'Index was outside of bounds of the array'

Tags: arrays, vb.net

Using visual basic. Trying to load a series of reports onto a listview, listview consists of 3 columns (location, date and severity level) everytime it loads it crashes due to 'index being outside the bounds of the array'.Specifically around DOI = reportdetails(1) in my code. It is loading off of a textfile. I have the data within the textfile so I am unsure of why it is saying I am asking for information that doesnt exist. The program also encypts the textfile.

```
Dim locate, DOI, SeverityLevel, ReportTitles, EReportTitles, ReportDetails(2) As String

Dim Index As Integer 'Define Variables
Dim FileNum As Integer = FreeFile()
Dim IncidentReport As ListViewItem

lstReports.Items.Clear()

If Dir("ReportTitles.txt") <> "" Then 'If the directory of the file exits then continue

    FileOpen(FileNum, "ReportTitles.txt", OpenMode.Input) 'open file
    Do Until EOF(FileNum)   'Repeat until the end of the file is reached

        EReportTitles = "" 'Clear variables, to safeguard against crashes or errors

        ReportTitles = ""
        EReportTitles = LineInput(FileNum) 'EReportTitles is equal to the current file line

        Dim FileName As String = "ReportTitles.txt"   'Define variables

        Dim I, C As Integer
        Dim Last As Integer = EReportTitles.Length - 1
        Dim ThisChar As Char
        For I = 0 To Last   'Begin for loop 
            ThisChar = EReportTitles.Chars(I)  'Decryption of file
            C = Asc(ThisChar) Xor 22
            ThisChar = Chr(C)
            ReportTitles += ThisChar
        Next
        If ReportTitles <> "" Then
            ReportDetails = Split(ReportTitles, ",")  'Split the lines when a "," is encountered

            locate = ReportDetails(0) 'Assosciate to relevant value in array

            DOI = ReportDetails(1)
            SeverityLevel = ReportDetails(2)

            IncidentReport = New ListViewItem
            IncidentReport.Text = locate    'Add relevant values to IncidentReport ListViewItem variable
            IncidentReport.SubItems.Add(DOI)
            IncidentReport.SubItems.Add(SeverityLevel)

            lstReports.Items.Add(IncidentReport)  'Transfer IncidentReport to listview
        Else

        End If
    Loop
    FileClose(FileNum)  'close file
End If
```

Expected result is to load all of the report location, dates and severity levels onto the listview.

Also sorry about the formatting of this question, i'm new to stack overflow.

Comment: There is not much we can do for you as this is primarily a data issue.  Set a breakpoint on the `If ReportTitles <> "" Then` and inspect the value or `ReportTitles` to see if you are getting what you expect (i.e. a comma seperated list).

Comment: The `FreeFile` and friends API is obsolete and should not be used in new code. It exists only for backwards compatibility when porting forward old vb6-era code.

Answer (score 2):

There's no point declaring `ReportDetails` like this:

```
ReportDetails(2) As String
```

because that creates an array that you never use.  Here:

```
ReportDetails = Split(ReportTitles, ",")
```

you are creating a new array anyway and the length of that array will be determined by the number of delimiters in `ReportTitles`.  If you're being told that 1 is an invalid index for that array then that array must only contain 1 element, which means that `ReportTitles` didn't contain any delimiters.

This is not something that we should have to explain to you because you can easily see it for yourself by debugging and you should ALWAYS debug BEFORE posting here.  Set a breakpoint at the top of the code, step through it line by line and examine the state at each step.  You can easily see the contents of `ReportTitles` and `ReportDetails` and anything else to see whether they are what you expect them to be.

If the point here is to read a CSV file then you really ought to be using the `TextFieldParser` class.  The documentation for that class includes a code example.

Answer (score 0):

This requires .Net Standard 2.1, and so I'm not sure if VB.Net can use the required `SpanAction` for the `String.Create()` method, but if it is supported it should greatly outperform the original.

```
lstReports.Items.Clear()

'Read and "Decrypt" (and I use that term loosely) the file with only a single heap allocation
Dim file As String
Using fs As FileStream = File.OpenRead("ReportTitles.txt")
    file = String.Create(fs.Length, fs, 
        Sub(chars, stream)
            For i As Integer = 0 To stream.Length - 1
                'THIS IS NOT ENCRYPTION! At best, it's obfuscation.
                chars(i) = Chr(fs.ReadByte() Xor 22)
            Next
        End Sub)
End Using

'Use an actual CSV parser
Using reader As New StringReader(file), _
      parser As New TextFieldParser(reader)

    parser.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
    parser.Delimiters = New String() {","}

    Dim row As String()

    While Not parser.EndOfData
        row = parser.ReadFields()

        If row.Length >= 3 Then
            Dim IncidentReport As New ListViewItem()
            IncidentReport.Text = row(0) '
            IncidentReport.SubItems.Add(row(1))
            IncidentReport.SubItems.Add(row(2))

            lstReports.Items.Add(IncidentReport)  
        End If
    End While
End Using
```

If you are not able to use that version, this is not quite as good, but still a better approach than the original:

```
lstReports.Items.Clear()

'Load and "Decrypt" the file  
Dim file As String
Using fs As FileStream = File.OpenRead("ReportTitles.txt")
    Dim builder As New StringBuilder(fs.Length)
    For i As Integer = 0 To fs.Length - 1
        'THIS IS NOT ENCRYPTION! At best, it's obfuscation.
        builder.Append(Chr(fs.ReadByte() Xor 22))
    Next
    file = builder.ToString()
End Using

'Use an actual CSV parser
Using reader As New StringReader(file), _
      parser As New TextFieldParser(reader)

    parser.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
    parser.Delimiters = New String() {","}

    Dim row As String()

    While Not parser.EndOfData
        row = parser.ReadFields()

        If row.Length >= 3 Then
            Dim IncidentReport As New ListViewItem()
            IncidentReport.Text = row(0) '
            IncidentReport.SubItems.Add(row(1))
            IncidentReport.SubItems.Add(row(2))

            lstReports.Items.Add(IncidentReport)  
        End If
    End While
End Using
```

In both cases, use `Try/Catch` rather than `Dir()` to check whether the location exists. Just try to open the file. `Dir()` costs an extra disk seek, and there are precious few things in programming slower than disk I/O.